# PROGRESS BAR EN MOVIMIENTO

Tags: javascript, funciones, progressbar

Estoy haciendo un *drag&drop* que contiene un **progress bar** rojo o verde segun la carga sea valida o fallida.
Quiero que se me **cargue la barra cada vez que sube el archivo**, pero no lo hace asi, lo hace todo de golpe. ¿Cómo podria arreglarlo?

```
  const nFiles = validFiles.length //numero de archivos validos
    let porcentaje = 100 / nFiles //porcentaje que corresponde cada archivo
    
    const uploadModalRef = useRef();
    const uploadRef = useRef();
    const progressRef = useRef();

const uploadFiles = () => {
        uploadModalRef.current.style.display = 'block';
        uploadRef.current.innerHTML = `Está subiendo ${nFiles} archivos... <br>Se subirán en segundo plano`;
      
        // progressRef.current.style.width = `${progress}%`
        let progress = 0
        updateseeList(false)
       
        for (let i = 0; i < validFiles.length; i++) {
            console.log(i)
      
            //  progress = porcentaje
            progressRef.current.style.backgroundColor = '#8dd4bd';
            progress += porcentaje
            progressRef.current.style.width =`${progress}%` ;



            const formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('file', validFiles[i]);
            formData.append('key', 'add your API key here');
           axios.post('url', formData, {
           
                headers: {
                    // 'Accept': 'application/file',
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${UserService.getToken()}`
                },


            }


            )



                .catch(() => {
                    // If error, display a message on the upload modal
                    uploadRef.current.innerHTML = `<span class="error">Error Uploading File(s)</span>`;
                    // set progress bar background color to red
                    progressRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
                    progress += porcentaje
                    progressRef.current.style.width = `${progress}%`;
                });

            console.log(porcentaje)
            console.log(progress)
        }
    }


<button className="file-upload-btn" onClick={() => uploadFiles()}> //donde llamo a la funcion
```

Me sale directamente asi,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto el OK como el ERROR se me cargan directamente, y mi intención es que pinte el trocito correspondiente cada vez que pasa por el for

Comment: ¡Es que pasa por el for al instante! Deberías actualizar la barra cuando tengas la respuesta de la llamada post (usando `then(...)`)

Comment: donde tengo que colorcar el then??

Comment: Mira el uso de [axios.post](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example)

Comment: Se podría hacer también con async/await, pero esto ralentizaría la subida de ficheros

Answer (score 1):

Te voy a poner un ejemplo, que es tu escenario pero simplificado, para que entiendas mejor lo que está pasando:

```js
const progresoInmediato= document.querySelector('#inmediata');
const progresoRespuesta= document.querySelector('#respuesta');

//método que devuelve una promesa, como axios.post
function simulaPost(valor) {
  return new Promise(function(success,error) {
    setTimeout(()=>success(valor), 500 * valor);
  });
}

for (let i=0; i<5;i++) {
  console.log('hago la llamada con',i);
  progresoInmediato.value= i* 25;
  simulaPost(i)
    .then(respuesta => {
      console.log('Tengo la respuesta', respuesta);
      progresoRespuesta.value= i*25;
    });
}
```

```html
<label>en el FOR</label>
<progress id="inmediata" value="0" max="100"> </progress>
<br/>
<label>En el then</label>
<progress id="respuesta" value="0" max="100"> </progress>
```

Como puedes ver, el for se recorre al instante, no se espera a que cada promesa se resuelva.
Después, conforme pasa el tiempo y obtenemos respuestas, la función que se le pasa al método `then` se va ejecutando.

Por tanto, lo que necesitas es que la barra de progreso se vaya actualizando ahí:

```
for (let i = 0; i < validFiles.length; i++) {
  ... //más código
  axios.post('url', ...)
    .then(response => {
      //actualiza la barra de progreso
    })
    .catch(...); //ha habido un error
  }
}
```